# flutter change background on click

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to change the background color by clicking on the screen to random, I can't figure out how to do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:math';

main() => runApp(
  Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    child: Container(
      color: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  ),
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector( // используется как обычный виджет
        onTap: () { // одно из свойств GestureDetector
          // Этот метод будет вызван, когда дочерний элемент будет нажат
          print('You pressed me');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need to make a `StateFulWidget` because you want to change the background when tapped.

**2.** You need to make a list of colors that can be set as the background color.

**3.** You need to add a variable which holds the current background color's index in the list of colors.

**4.** You need to change this variable when tapped to set a new background color.

**Note:** If you want to have random colors you can check the [random_color](https://pub.dev/packages/random_color) package which is easy to use.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: "Title"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Color> _colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.yellow];
  var _index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: _colors[_index % _colors.length],
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _index++;
          });
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: There is no need for a `list of colors` here. The OP  question stated to generate Random colors.

Comment: I don't know if he/she meant picking a color randomly or generating random colors or even a random tap on the screen. @Derek

Comment: I assume he/she meant generate random background color each time a tap is detected.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you want to store the color as part of the state of the widget that you want. Then, when you detect a press, you can change the color and call [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) to trigger a rebuild to show the new color. This involves modifying your code to use a [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) as I have done below.

The following code uses the exact same widgets as your original, with just modifications to make the necessary parts stateful.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:math';

main() => runApp(
  Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    child: MyApp(),
  ),
);

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {//Changed to a `StatefulWidget`
  
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  //Store the color as a part of your `State`
  Color color = Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            
            print('You pressed me');

            //`setState` rebuilds your widget to show the new color
            //It's not possible to use a `StatelessWidget` here
            setState(() {
              color = Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Color color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    color = Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          color = Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
              .withOpacity(1.0);
        });
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: color,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```